# Avoid scrollbar when accordion is expanded

Tags: html, css

On the page below I have accordion at the middle of the page.

When the elements of the accordion are expanded, scrollbar appears.

How to get rid of this scrollbar ? I would like the height to adjust according to accordion height.

Comment: Do I seriously need to scroll trough multiple advertisements to see what you're talking about?

Comment: This is a testing website with fake data. No advertisements at all.

Answer (score 0):

In the main div right after the `<body>` tag, change the style to include `overflow: hidden;` so,

```
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;text-align:center;overflow:hidden;">
```

But your code also just needs to be completely reworked, you have an entirely different html, head, and body, within the body of another html tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a `<body>` inside another `<body>`. Try using a `<div>` instead.

Also be ware of the GoogleMaps API. Console says:

> js?key=AIzaSyASIEMWw7Bw_mzMSH5fTYVbeb-ljj0ryzs&_=1468350321595:92 You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.

Answer (score 0):

Hey took a look and go it working for you. This is the mods i made to your code

Starting with the first div in your iframe i set the overflow:hidden. Same with the next div.

Then with your accordion-container I added overflow:hidden

```
.accordion-container {
   width: 800px;
   margin: 0 0 20px;
   clear: both;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Finally with your accordion-content it has overflow:auto

```
.accordion-content {
   display: block;
   padding: 20px;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Looking at it again it's really only the overflow hidden on the first div of the iframe that is necessary along with the oveflow:auto; on the accordion-content